# Rounding off a float value without decimal points in python 2

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point

Problem is to round-off the resulting value without any decimals after summation of percentage values using Python 2. provided 3 inputs

Input 1 (meal cost) : 10.25

Input 2 (tip  percentage) : 17

Input 3 (tax percentage) : 5

I have to calculate tip amount and tax amount and added the result with meal cost.

I tried below code:

def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):

```
 tip_amt = (meal_cost * tip_percent)/100
 tax_amt =(meal_cost * tax_percent)/100
 total_bill = (meal_cost + tip_amt + tax_amt)
 print int (total_bill)
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
meal_cost = float(raw_input())

tip_percent = int(raw_input())

tax_percent = int(raw_input())

solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent)
```

Right answer is 13. But above code gives 12.

Please guide me to get the expected result with solution.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the rounded-off sum value to integer gives expected value without decimals.

```
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
     tip_amt = (meal_cost * tip_percent)/100
     tax_amt =(meal_cost * tax_percent)/100
     total_bill = (meal_cost + tip_amt + tax_amt)
     round_total = round(total_bill)
     return int(round_total)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be using round off.

```
tip_amt = meal_cost * tip_percent/100
tax_amt =meal_cost * tax_percent/100
total_bill = meal_cost + tip_amt + tax_amt
print round(total_bill)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Manoj. I tried round also. But it is giving output with one decimal point. (13.0)

Comment: convert round of value to int

Comment: Yeah..That worked Manoj. Converting the rounded-off value to integer gives expected value without decimals. Thanks a lot!!!